# What is Hadith Qudsi?

Tags: hadith

Can anyone elaborate on Hadith Qudsi ?

What I know is that they are considered as the **Word of God expressed in Muhammad's Words**

Comment: Hadith Qudsi are mainly collected by Hurr Al-Amili in 11th Islamic century. There is a lot of debate on their authenticity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hadith Qudsi (or Sacred Hadith) is a sub-category of hadith which are sayings of prophet Muhammad (SAWW). 
Muslims regard the Hadith Qudsi as the words of God 
, repeated by prophet Muhammad (SAWW) and recorded on the condition of a sanad (document).

According to as-Sayyid ash-Sharif al-Jurjani, the Hadith Qudsi differ from the Quran in that the former are "expressed in Muhammad's words", whereas the latter are the "direct words of God".

[Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith)

Answer (score 4):

According to [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=18457), Hadith Qudsi is what was said by the Prophet Mohammad (PBUH), but it's meaning was from Allah, or what God sent to him by inspiration or a dream, so Prophet Mohammad said it in his own words but with the same meaning. That's why it seems as if God was saying this.

Answer (score 4):

Hadith Qudsi is sayings from God. But is different of Quran. In Quran both concept and words are revealed to the Prophet from God but in Hadith Qudsi only concept (meaning) is revealed to prophet and prophet express it by his own words. Also another difference is that the Hadith Qudsi is not miracle.

**Reference:**

http://www.nekoonam.ir/allbooktxt/7/index.html

Answer (score 0):

In the name of Allah the merciful the compassionate

Hadith Qudsi is a direct Saying of Allah JJR, transmitted to us through Prophets(S). Allamah Sayyid Muhammad Husayn at-Tabataba'i writes in his book entitled "A Shi'ite Anthology" about the context of these hadiths:

> The sayings of the Imams are in many ways not only a continuation but
>   also a kind of commentary and elucidation of the prophetic Hadith,
>   often with the aim of bringing out the esoteric teachings of Islam.
>   Many of these hadiths deal, like those of the Blessed Prophet, with
>   the practical aspects of life and the Shari'ah. Others deal with pure
>   metaphysics, as do certain prophetic hadiths, especially the "sacred
>   hadiths" (hadith qudsi).

Hadith Qudsi (Sacred tradition) is one of; the sources which opens up our eyes and awakens us so that we may think. For example:

> "O Son of Adam! Obey Me to the extent of your deeds towards Me.
>   Disobey Me to the extent of your ability to tolerate the Fire of Hell.
>   Collect wealth in this world according to the length of your stay
>   here. Collect for the Hereafter (Aakhirah) according to the length of
>   your stay here. Do not think that your death is far and that the
>   Bounties (you receive from Allah) will always be available, or that
>   your sins are hidden." (Al-Hadith Al-Qudsi, Hadith No.13)

The Hadith Qudsi is scattered but some efforts have been done to gather them into one book (such as the book by Aqai Sayyid Hassan Shirazi).
Almighty Allah says in another Hadith Qudsi:

> O, Son of Adam! Be patient and be humble and I will elevate you. Thank
>   Me and I will increase your bounties. Seek pardon from Me, and I will
>   forgive you. Call upon Me, I will answer you. Ask of Me, I will
>   provide for you. Give alms in My way, and I will bless you with
>   bounties. Be kind towards your relatives, and I will add to your age
>   by delaying death. Seek from Me good health as long as you are
>   healthy. And while you are alone seek safety from Me. Seek sincerity
>   in purity. Seek piety in repentance (Tawba). Seek worship in
>   knowledge. Seek independence in contentment. O, Son of Adam! How can
>   you be curious of worship when your stomach is full? How can you
>   enlighten your heart by sleeping a lot? How can you have fear of Allah
>   with fear of poverty? How can you seek the pleasure of Almighty Allah
>   by degrading the poor and the beggars?

The following book may present detailed information about these hadiths:

> AI-Hadith al-Qudsi: a werd of Allah/[Taken from the book
>   "Kalimatullah" of Hassan Shirazi]; Translated by S.M. Zaki Baqri.-
>   Qum: Ansariyan, 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Hadith Qudsi is sayings from God. But is different of Quran. In Quran both concept and words are revealed to the Prophet from God but in Hadith Qudsi only concept (meaning) is revealed to prophet and prophet express it by his own words. Also another difference is that the Hadith Qudsi is not miracle.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Answers here should be elaborate, and focused on answering the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help), and refer to [how to answer questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

اَلسَلامُ عَلَيْكُم وَرَحْمَةُ اَللهِ وَبَرَكاتُهُ‎
The Hadith al-Al qudsi is a Hadith that Almighty  Allah revealed the meaning to the Prophet (S)  but the word expressed by Prophet (S).

Answer (score -2):

Al Hamduli Lah!
Ad Salaamu alai kum wa rahmantullahi!:

Al hadiith Al Qudsi is when Allah Ta Ala Speaks To The Common People Through The Prophet! The  Prophet Muhammad (Salli Allahu Alayhi Salam) is A Living Oracle Of Allah Subanna Hu WA Ta Ala when this occurs! Matthew ch.6:v.33 is Hadiith Al Qudsi!

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider reading [answer], checking our .[help] and taking our [tour] to learn more about this site.